# Displaying Records based on keyword from vf page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have a senario where i will be dispalying input text fieldon vf page ,when i enter some value and click on search button the realted accounts should be displayed depending on  that keyword.
I have tried the following code ,but i am unable to resolve the error **Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'**
The below is my code:
class:

```
public class AccountswithKeywordfrompage {
    public string keyword{get;set;}
    public List<List<Account>> accountlist{get;set;}
    public void Accounts(){
        keyword = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('search');
        accountlist=[FIND '+keyword' IN ALL FIELDS 
                     RETURNING Account(Name)];
    }
}
```

vf page:

<apex:page controller="AccountswithKeywordfrompage" standardStylesheets="false">

```
 <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText label="SearchAccounts" id="search">
            <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!Accounts}"/>
        </apex:inputText> 
        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accountlist}" var="accountobj">
                <apex:outputlink value="{!accountobj.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>   
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

`accountlist` is a `List<List<Account>>`, which is the wrong type; a SOSL search returns a `List<List<sObject>>`. It just so happens that your SOSL search only returns Account results.

When you iterate over a `List<List<sObject>>`:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!accountlist}" var="accountobj">
```

the type of the iteration variable is `List<Account>`, which has no `Name` property.

The cleanest solution is to declare your variable as a `List<Account>` and extract the first element of the returned `List<List<sObject>>` from SOSL.

Comment: When i replace the things that you said 
still i am getting some error like
Unknown property 'AccountswithKeywordfrompage.list'
And can you please explain me how to get the list vallues that are returned from controller class to vf page